# How can I create a keystore Visual studio 2015 apache cordova?

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

What are the steps to create a keystore for android Visual studio 2015 apache cordova?

```
key.store=
key.alias=
key.store.password=
key.alias.password=
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read all about this here: [Package Your App Built with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757048.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Android)

Also, for creating a keystore, here are instructions: [Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html). I manually created keystore for my app using these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an official video tutorial on how to sign your Android APK file with Vistual Studio 2015.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_E1kCMsdd4